# How to break word in list item of bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having a list using bootstrap 4, but some item inside contain long text, it causes problem on small screen device. I tried to use `white-space:nowrap` or class `text-nowrap`, but nothing occur.
Is there anyway to fix this?

My code:

```
<ul class='navbar-nav'>
   <li class='nav-item'>
       <a href='#' class='text-nowrap'>long textt...........</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
<ul class='navbar-nav'>
   <li class='nav-item'>
       <a href='#'>long textt...........</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

```
.nav-item {
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7wc3L8bh/ - real example

---

If it is, than you should use Bootstrap 4 class `text-truncate`

See its documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow) (Note, that it requres `block` element)

---

If it is not, and you want your text to be visible on the next line - use class `text-nowrap`.

See its documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#word-break) (Note, element should have fixed `width`)

Comment: With using ````text-nowrap````, can i set ````width```` of ````a```` tags to 100%, inherit the ````li```` cover them?

Comment: Yes, why not) But I think class `text-nowrap` should be added to `li` elements instead of `a`

Answer (score 0):

Prevent long strings of text from breaking your components’ layout by using .text-break to set word-wrap: break-word and word-break: break-word. We use word-wrap instead of the more common overflow-wrap for wider browser support, and add the deprecated word-break: break-word to avoid issues with flex containers.

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a href="#" class="text-break">long textt...........</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/#word-break

Comment: I tried to add, but look like it still not exists in bootstrap 4.0

Comment: let's add some css by yourself if your framework hasn't had it 
.text-break {
    word-break: break-word!important;
    word-wrap: break-word!important;
}